# How should I solve this birthday probability problem?

Tags: probability

Question: What is the least number of people such that there is a greater than $50\%$ chance that one of the people in the group has a birthday on February $29$?

My solution: Let $n$ be the number of people in this group. Then $\frac{_nC_1\cdot (365)^{n-1}}{(365)^n}>50\%$. However, the function on the left hand side can never reach $0.5$. Where was I wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126793/discussion-on-question-by-andy-z-how-should-i-solve-this-birthday-probability-pr).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing to do is to decide the probability that any one person has a birthday on Feb. 29th, and to assume that these probabilities are uniform and independent (clearly not quite true in practice). Roughly speaking, leap years occur every four years, so the probability is about $p=1/(4*365+1)$.

Then we apply the classic birthday problem  probability trick of calculating the odds that nobody's birthday is on Feb. 29. With $n$ people, and $P$ denoting the odds that someone's birthday is on Feb. 29 is

$$1-P = (1-p)^n$$.

From there we can solve for $n$ such that $P=1/2$. This should be a non-integer, so we then go to the smallest integer greater than our number to get the number of people to ensure $P>1/2$.